# Игра на UI элементах

Tags: unity3d

можно ли или правильно ли создавать игру полностью на элементах ui?

Comment: Можно. Иногда правильно. Трехмерные гонки или Свою Игру имеете ввиду? ;-)

Comment: Не совсем понял) делается обычная настольная игра, вернее перенос настолки на экран телефона

Comment: Все зависит от того какая игра. Настолок тожде бывает огромное количество видов. Дополните вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, но не правильно :) Canvas пересчитывается целиком при изменении любого элемента внутри. Т.е. сдвинув чуть в сторону один спрайт вы вызовете перерасчёт положений всех элементов.

Если, конечно, вся ваша игра не состоит только лишь из сплошных панелей.

Если сравнить две игры - на спрайтах и на канвасе, вторая будет грузить систему значительно сильнее

Comment: Так собственно и есть, около 40 панелек, которые как бы визуально обозначают клетки игрового поля, по ним бегает фишка игрока, вот собственно и вся игра) выбор в сторону ui был сделан из-за легкой адаптации к разным разрешениям и размерам экрана

Comment: Не будет. Если Canvas'ы нормально разбить и иерархию построить, то будет всё нормально работать и не будет перерасчётов бесконечных.